# How to filter content by language with WPGlobus

Tags: theme-development, recent-posts

I am new in PHP and I cannot find the way or the programming logic to do this filter.

I have the following code but I do not know how to filter it, 
Can anyone help me with the code?

```
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'numberposts' => 3, 
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'post_status' => 'publish'
        );

        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args, ARRAY_A );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
            echo '<div class="col-md-4"><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"], 'full', array('class' => 'img-responsive ') ) . '<h5>'. $recent["post_title"].'</h5></a> </div> ';
        }
        wp_reset_query();
    ?>
```

The options with WPGlobus are:

```
WPGlobus::Config()->language
```

or

```
WPGlobus_Core::text_filter( $text, $language );
```

or

```
$text = apply_filters( 'the_title', $text );
```

How to add language filter to this recent post code??

Answer (score 1):

In this part of the code:

`'<h5>'. $recent["post_title"].'</h5>`

the post_title should be filtered for WPGlobus to get the current language part.

Like this:

`'<h5>'. apply_filters( 'the_title', $recent['post_title'] ) .'</h5>`

Comment: May you please elaborate on how this code help solves this question?

Comment: Edited the answer. Hope it's more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar for `get_permalink`?